# All boolean possibilities of given length in J

Tags: j

I want the simplest verb that gives a list of all boolean lists of given length.

e.g.

```
   f=. NB. Insert magic here

   f 2
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1

   f 3
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Comment: `(y#2) #: 2^y` and a variety of riffs on that theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality has been recently added to the `stats/base` addon.

```
   load 'stats/base/combinatorial'  NB. or just load 'stats'
   permrep 2    NB. permutations of size 2 from 2 items with replacement
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
   3 permrep 2  NB. permutations of size 3 from 2 items with replacement
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
   permrep      NB. display definition of permrep
$:~ :(# #: i.@^~)
```

Using the Qt IDE you can view the script defining `permrep` and friends by entering `open 'stats/base/combinatorial'` in the Term window. Alternatively you can [view it on Github](https://github.com/jsoftware/stats_base/blob/master/combinatorial.ijs).

To define `f` as specified in your question, the following should suffice:

```
   f=: permrep&2
   f=: (# #: i.@^~)&2  NB. alternatively
   f 3
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#:` ("Antibase 2") vocab page has an example close to what I want. I don't really understand that primitive but the following code gives a list of base 2 digits of the numbers 0 to 2^n-1:

```
   f=. #:@i.@(2^])
```

(Thanks to Dan for getting me to look up `#:`.)